# Where did voting systems start?

Tags: discussion, voting

I'm just curious if people know where *online* voting systems started.

First there was Digg, then there was .. ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Slashdot](http://slashdot.org/) predates Digg by about 7 years, and [Slash](http://www.slashcode.com/) has a voting system built in.  I think it is (or at least, was) the canonical example of user-vote based moderation.

Answer (score 14):

Well, the greeks invented democracy.

Comment: The Greeks stole it form Digg, everyone knows that.

Comment: If this continue to be upvoted, I will embrace it and accept this answer.  When asked about the history of the internet, I shall point only to the Greeks.

Comment: It's getting late, so I thought that you wrote: the GEEKS invented democracy. It would be so fitting as an answer.

Comment: @Phoshi: By popular belief - yes , per Wikipedia, no: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_democracy

Answer (score 5):

**Semi-serious answer:** The first "Me too" post on the usenet.

Which would have been some September sometime in the 70's...